# Minus date calculation with GWT

Tags: java, gwt

Here is my try to do date minus for GWT:

```
Date from = new Date();
Date to = new Date();

    if(filter.equals(DATE_FILTER.PAST_HOUR)){
        minusHoursToDate(to, 1);
    } else if(filter.equals(DATE_FILTER.PAST_24_HOURS)){
        minusHoursToDate(to, 1 * 24);
    } else if(filter.equals(DATE_FILTER.PAST_WEEK)){
        minusHoursToDate(to, 1 * 24 * 7);
    } else if(filter.equals(DATE_FILTER.PAST_MONTH)){
        minusHoursToDate(to, 1 * 24 * 7 * 4);
    } else if(filter.equals(DATE_FILTER.PAST_YEAR)){
        minusHoursToDate(to, 1 * 24 * 7 * 4 * 12);
    }

public static void minusHoursToDate(Date date, int hours){
    date.setTime(date.getTime() - (hours * 3600000));
}
```

The problem I see here is with the calculation in terms of month and year. As months is not always 4-week aligned and a year is also affected. 
What could be the best calculation for subtracting month & year?

Comment: how to concern with GWT ?

Comment: I think your error is using the same object. After update your object once , the calculation of next time will be effect via last updated result. And check for using static method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `java.util.Calendar` is unsupported in GWT because of the complexity needed for its implementation, the final JS size, etc, I would go with a simple and lightweight solution based on JS.

Apart from the java `Date` implementation, in GWT we have the `JsDate` wrapper which includes all the methods available in the native JS date, so subtracting a month or a year should be as simpler as:

```
    int months = -2;
    int years = -3;
    JsDate j = JsDate.create(new Date().getTime());
    j.setMonth(j.getMonth() + months);
    j.setFullYear(j.getFullYear() + years);
    Date d = new Date((long)j.getTime());
```

You can do the same to manipulate other units:

```
    getDate()   Returns the day of the month (from 1-31)
    getDay()    Returns the day of the week (from 0-6)
    getFullYear()   Returns the year (four digits)
    getHours()  Returns the hour (from 0-23)
    getMilliseconds()   Returns the milliseconds (from 0-999)
    getMinutes()    Returns the minutes (from 0-59)
    getMonth()  Returns the month (from 0-11)
    getSeconds()    Returns the seconds (from 0-59)
```